# Is continuity in topology well-defined?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In topology, a function is continuous if inverse of every open set is open. But for the inverse to be well-defined the function should be bijective. For example consider the projection map. It is not injective: $\pi_1(x,y_1)=\pi_1(x,y_2)=x$ with $y_1\neq y_2$. But still it continuous and continuity is proved using the inverse function.

Comment: This is an unfortunate, and even sadder not unique, case of lousy notation and/or naming. Hayden's answer covers this.

Comment: It is "inverse image" (also called pre-image) of an open set, not inverse of an open set. And this does not involve any inverse function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We say that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map if given any open set $U\subset Y$, then $f^{-1}[U]$ is an open set in $X$.  This isn't the inverse map we are using, but a related notion called the "pre-image":

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function, and for $B\subset Y$, define the **pre-image** of $B$ to be
$$f^{-1}[B]=\{x\in X \mid f(x) \in B\}$$
This definition does not require $f$ to be bijective at all, and *it* is what is being denoted whenever $f^{-1}$ is mentioned.

(It is also common to use parentheses rather than square brackets, but I've always felt that using the latter is better for being clear about what is meant.)

Worth mentioning is that this induces a map $f^{-1}[\cdot]:\mathcal{P}(Y)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ given by sending $B\subset Y$ to $f^{-1}[B]$.  There is also the related map $f[\cdot]:\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$ sending $A\subset X$ to 
$$f[A]:=\{b\in Y \mid \text{there exists $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=b$}\}$$
This also induces a map $f[\cdot]:\mathcal{P}(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{P}(Y)$ sending $A$ to $f[A]$.

However, in general $f^{-1}[\cdot]$ and $f[\cdot]$ are not inverses!  In fact, they are inverses if and only if $f$ has an inverse, for we can consider $f[f^{-1}[\{y\}]]$ and $f^{-1}[f[\{x\}]]$ for $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.  Injectivity of $f$ provides the identity 
$$f^{-1}[f[A]]=A$$
 and surjectivity of $f$ provides the identity 
$$f[f^{-1}[B]]=B.$$

Comment: So here we can't use $f(f^{-1}(A))=f^{-1}(f(A))=A$?

Comment: @MathewGeorge Nope, that doesn't hold in general.  Take for example the constant map $f_{y_0}:X\rightarrow Y$ defined by $f_{y_0}(x)=y_0$ for every $x\in X$.  If $Y\neq \{y_0\}$, then $f[f^{-1}[Y\setminus\{y_0\}]]=f[\emptyset]=\emptyset\neq Y\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: @MathewGeorge The second identity might also fail; take the same map as in Hayden's example, then $f^{-1}[f[{x}]]=f^{-1}[{y_0}]=X$ for any point $x\in X$.

Comment: This is why it's important to get used to the idea of a function as a relation: there are aspects of the function as a relation that exist and are true regardless of whether or not the set of ordered pairs really IS a function or not. All relations have inverse images. In this case,we really should call it the "inverse image" when talking to beginners to avoid such notational confusion.

Comment: I suspect even the phrase "inverse image" will occasionally be confused with the notion of "image under the inverse function" and thus raise the question of whether the function has an inverse. Any notation using $f^{-1}$ is liable to be initially confusing in the case where you know there's no such *function* as $f^{-1}$.

Comment: You do have that $f[f^{-1}[B]]\subseteq B$ and $A\subseteq f^{-1}[f[A]]$

Answer (score 2):

The inverse-image of a set $S$ under a function $f$ is the set $\{x : f(x)\in S\}$.  This exists regardless of whether the inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question.

Comment: @MathewGeorge: The history does not show that the question was edited at all; it is not clear which change you mean.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen : The question was edited, changing "a" to "every".